# How to turn off specific notification types on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

In the first version of my app, I registered it with:

```
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge).
```

This is how I did it:

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Now in the second version of my app, I decided to abandon the badge notification by registering notifications again with this:

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

I was expecting the badge notifications would be turned off from now on.  When I went into the settings menu and checked the notification settings for my app. The toggle switch for badge was gone, but the badge number was still getting updated.

I suspect that my approach only unregistered UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge, but not turning it off. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the badge notifications weren't turned off, but if you decided to abandon badge notifications, you can disable them in the server side. Simply don't send the badge number in the JSON payload of the push notifications you are sending.

Even if you manage to disable badge notifications in the client side, you should still disable it at your server side anyway, in order not to waste CPU and bandwidth on computing and sending data that your client will not use.

Comment: Thanks. That would be my last resort, but I am still curious if there is a way to turn it off.